# Issue storing multi valued json format dictionary into mysql table in DJango

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have below ajax call in my template

**temp.html**

```
function saveprof() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "saveprof",
                async: true,
                data: {
                    'radinput_Aj' : fun(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#message').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

fun() returns a json format object v - which is as below :

example :

```
var v = [
             { axis: "", value: 4, order: 0 },
             { axis: "", value: 4, order: 1 },
             { axis: "", value: 4, order: 2 },
             { axis: "", value: 4, order: 3 },
             { axis: "", value: 4, order: 4 },
             { axis: "", value: 4, order: 5 },
             { axis: "", value: 4, order: 6 }
    ];
```

**Views.py**

```
def saveprof(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    radinputV=[]
    radinputV = request.POST.get('radinput_Aj')
else:
    response_data = 'Nothing to update!'
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
response_data = ''
try:
*(Here, I would like to insert the incoming dictionary (radinputV) rows into my model skills)*
except:
    response_data = 'Ouch! Something went wrong!'
return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
```

Below is the **skills** model :

```
class skills(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
skill = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
rating = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
ordernum = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
```

Here is the mapping of incoming json dictionary from template with the fields in skills model -
skill is axis,
rating is value,
ordernum is order

In the view :

```
radinputV=[]
radinputV = request.POST.get('radinput_Aj')
radinputV1 = request.POST.get('radinput_Aj[0][value]')
```

I can access dictionary item by using above notation.

However, if I use above notation, I would need to write 21 statements like this (7 rows * 3 columns) of Dictionary object V... is there a simple way for this ?

How to handle this scenario of inserting multiple rows into mysql table from template JSON object - Django view ?

**Edited** with the latest try using get method.

Comment: While debugging, I see no value in radinputV  when i used get method like this.. radinputV=[]
        radinputV = request.POST.get('radinput_Aj').. But I could see the dictionary in the POST message  - I'm using Visual Studio

Comment: Please show your template, and the code that's responsible for calling the `saveProf` function.

Comment: Hi Daniel, template is a huge one.. but I could text the relevant code which calls saveProf().. it is just a hyperlink  <a class="sp" href="javascript:saveprof();">Save</a>...

Comment: I am able to view the dictionary items by using this notation in the view..           radinputV = request.POST.get('radinput_Aj')
        radinputV1 = request.POST.get('radinput_Aj[0][value]')
. But if I use above notation, I would nee to write 21 statements for that dict object (7*3).. how can I store all the 7 rows into my skills model, any simple method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a data structure like this via standard form parameters. You need to serialize it to JSON before sending, and then deserialize it in the view.

Change the `data` parameter as follows:

```
data: {
    'radinput_Aj' : JSON.stringify(fun()),
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
},
```

and the view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.POST.get('radinput_Aj')
    radinputV = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Well, now you can just iterate through and create a Skill object in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for helping!.. I will do it.